# Test if value of key in array exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object:

```
[ { id:
     '/subscriptions/resourcegroups/coco-test/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-runscripts2',
    name: 'shutdown-computevm-runscripts2' },
  { id:
     '/subscriptions/resourcegroups/coco-test/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-packer',
    name: 'shutdown-computevm-packer' } ]
```

I am trying to write a script that does something if it can't find a specific value in the `name` key of any of this object.

Example: `shutdown-computevm-test`

If there is no name anywhere in this object that matches this value, then I want my code to do something.
I'm new to nodejs, I tried things like `includes()`, `indexOf` etc, but these are either not the correct ways to do it or I never got the syntax right.
Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Please show exactly what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you;

```js
const result = [ { id:
     '/subscriptions/resourcegroups/coco-test/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-runscripts2',
    name: 'shutdown-computevm-runscripts2' },
  { id:
     '/subscriptions/resourcegroups/coco-test/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-packer',
    name: 'shutdown-computevm-packer' } ];

const found = result.some((part) => part.name === 'shutdown-computevm-test');

if (! found) {
  // do something here
}
```

I prefer it to filter as it won't wait to iterate over all items in the array and will shortcut as soon as it is found.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const arr = [ { id:
     '/subscriptions/resourcegroups/coco-test/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-runscripts2',
    name: 'shutdown-computevm-runscripts2' },
  { id:
     '/subscriptions/resourcegroups/coco-test/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-packer',
    name: 'shutdown-computevm-packer' } ]


let rs = arr.find(item => item.name === 'shutdown-computevm')
let rs2 = arr.find(item => item.name === 'shutdown-computevm-runscripts2')
console.log(rs) // undefined
console.log(rs2) // obj
```